# How to resolve org.springframework.jms.config.JMSListenerEndpointRegister.isAutoStartUp()Z Error?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jms

So I am building a project using Spring Framework 4.3.20.RELEASE. It is sending and receiving messages to/from a JMS server (in this case I have it on `localhost`).

I am able to send message to queue but unable to get it from there. Here is my `consumer` class and `consumerConfig` classes.

Here are my dependencies in POM

```xml
<!-- JMS -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
    <version>5.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is my `ConsumerConfig` class:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class ReceiverConfig {

    private String brokerUrl = "tcp://localhost:61616";

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory receiverActiveMQConnectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);

        return activeMQConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(receiverActiveMQConnectionFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency("1-1");

        return factory;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Receiver receiver() {
        return new Receiver();
    }
}
```

and Consumer Class

```java
public class Receiver {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Receiver.class);

    @Autowired
    private Processor processor;

    @JmsListener(destination = "my.queue", containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
    public void receive(String message) {
        logger.info("We have read message " + message + " from Queue");
    }
}
```

And the Error I am getting

```
[2020-03-24 04:57:53,405] Artifact {my-project}:war: java.lang.Exception: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host.\"/{my-project}\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host.\"/{my-project}\": java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerEndpointRegistry.isAutoStartup()Z
    Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerEndpointRegistry.isAutoStartup()Z"},"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host.\"/{my-project}\""],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined}
```

Comment: You have some mismatched jars- you mention Spring 4.3.20 but your spring-jms jar is 5.1.5. All spring-* jars must be the same version.

Comment: yeah I literally solved it a few seconds ago and yes, the reason was the mismatch of spring-framework dependency versions.